# How to wrap div around multiple of the same class elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to wrap multiple same class divs into a div and to skip divs not with the same class. .wrap doesn't combine them, and .wrapAll throws the non-classed divs underneath. I've been tinkering around with attempts to create an alternate solution but with no avail.

Original:

```
<div class="entry">Content</div>
<div class="entry">Content</div>
<div class="entry">Content</div>
<div>Skip in wrap</div>
<div class="entry">Content</div>
<div class="entry">Content</div>
<div class="entry">Content</div>

    continued...
```

Wanted Result:

```
<div>
    <div class="entry">Content</div>
    <div class="entry">Content</div>
    <div class="entry">Content</div>
</div>
<div>Skip in wrap</div>
<div>
    <div class="entry">Content</div>
    <div class="entry">Content</div>
    <div class="entry">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: same as meder. The function you are trying to use cannot "guess" what you want to do, or else there would be too much overhead and would render the function impracticable

Comment: I agree, javascript shouldn't be used to make such drastic changes. However, the software I'm using doesn't allow you to edit any changes to the setup, so I'm stuck with jQuery.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can loop pretty quickly through your `<div>` elements using a `for` loop.  In the below code, just change the initial selector here to grab all those siblings divs, e.g. `#content > div.entry` or wherever they are:

```
var divs = $("div.entry");
for(var i=0; i<divs.length;) {
  i += divs.eq(i).nextUntil(':not(.entry)').andSelf().wrapAll('<div />').length;
}​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Uv6Dr/3/).  We're just looping through, the `.entry` `<div>` elements using [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to get all the `.entry` elements until there is a non-`.entry` one using the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).  Then we're taking those next elements, plus the one we started with ([`.andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/)) and doing a [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) on that group.  After they're wrapped, we're skipping ahead either that many elements in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I just whipped up a simple [custom solution](http://jsfiddle.net/D9nGp/).

```
var i, wrap, wrap_number = 0;
$('div').each(function(){ //group entries into blocks "entry_wrap_#"
    var div = $(this);
    if (div.is('.entry')) {
        wrap = 'entry_wrap_' + wrap_number;
        div.addClass(wrap);
    } else {
        wrap_number++;
    }
});
for (i = 0; i <= wrap_number; i++) { //wrap all blocks and remove class
    wrap = 'entry_wrap_' + i;
    $('.' + wrap).wrapAll('<div class="wrap"/>').removeClass(wrap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively append new divs to your markup, and then append the content you want wrapped into those.

If your markup is this:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-1"></div>
  <div class="col-2"></div>
  <div class="col-2"></div>
  <div class="col-2"></div>
  <div class="col-2"></div>
  <div class="col-2"></div>
</div>
```

Use the following to append two new divs (`column-one` and `column-two`) and then append the appropriate content into those divs:

```
// Set vars for column content
var colOne = $('.col-1').nextUntil('.col-2').addBack();
var colTwo = $('.col-2').nextAll().addBack();

// Append new divs that will take the column content
$('.wrap').append('<div class="column-first group" /><div class="column-second ground" />');

// Append column content to new divs
$(colOne).appendTo('.column-first');
$(colTwo).appendTo('.column-second');
```

Demo here: http://codepen.io/zgreen/pen/FKvLH