# How to wrap repeating blocks of html with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm writing a custom page for a wordpress blog. Plenty of content gets injected in by PHP on the fly.  I've had to add some CSS classes to dynamically created html tags with jQuery. I'm stuck on this one...

How would I wrap these "repeating video-blocks" my user will be creating on this wordpress page with a div?

A few note: All elements inside of div.entry-content have the class of '3'. Classes '1' & '2' are element specific classes.

```
<div class="canvas">
<div class="entry-content">

    <p class="1 3">Title-1</p>
    <div class="2 3">_____</div>
    <p class="3">Video Here</p> 
    <!- End of first "repeating video-block" -->

    <p class="1 3">Title-2</p>
    <div class="2 3">_____</div>
    <p class="3">Video Here</p>

    <p class="1 3">Title-3</p>
    <div class="2 3">_____</div>
    <p class="3">Video Here</p>

</div>
</div>
```

This is as close as I've been to making it work. http://jsfiddle.net/djfrsn/mq5ww/2/

```
var above      = $('.2').prev();
var below      = $('.2').after();
var videoBlock = '<div></div>';
$(below).addBack().wrapAll(videoBlock);
```

So far my resources have been the DOM traversal documents over @ jQuery website & this stack overflow post([jQuery How to wrap div around multiple of the same class elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328208/jquery-how-to-wrap-div-around-multiple-of-the-same-class-elements)) which seems to come close to what I need, although no luck so far.

Here is my desired output:

```
<div class="canvas">
<div class="entry-content">

    <div class="vid-block">
        <p class="1 3">Title-1</p>
        <div class="2 3">_____</div>
        <p class="3">Video Here</p> 
    </div> <!- End of first "repeating video-block" -->

    <div class="vid-block">
        <p class="1 3">Title-2</p>
        <div class="2 3">_____</div>
        <p class="3">Video Here</p> 
    </div>

    <div class="vid-block">
        <p class="1 3">Title-3</p>
        <div class="2 3">_____</div>
        <p class="3">Video Here</p> 
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/mq5ww/4/

```
$(".1").each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil(".1").addBack().wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'>");
});
```

Comment: Darn your speedy-edits, I had a scathing retort half-typed about `andSelf()`, but your correction robbed me of the opportunity, and left me feeling guilty, so I had to +1. Well played, sir..! ;)

Comment: @DavidThomas Hah, sorry to spoil your fun.  I have the hardest time remembering `addBack` for some reason `andSelf` just made sense to me.  I actually did at some point go back and edit old answers of mine to change it.

Comment: Haha, not a problem (and it wasn't that scathing, was just going to say it was either deprecated or removed, can't remember which, and point to the API). And yes: for some reason `addBack()` *feels* (from the name of the method) less intuitive, somehow.