# Wrap elements with new element depending on parent and/or class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three different div classes: design-box-triple, double, and single. There are multiple divs with the varying classes and they are all float left to be responsive.

```
<div class="collageWidgets">
    <div class="design-box-double"></div> <!--width 50%-->
    <div class="design-box-triple"></div> <!--width 33%-->
    <div class="design-box-triple"></div> <!--width 33%-->
    <div class="design-box-triple"></div> <!--width 33%-->
    <div class="design-box-double"></div> <!--width 50%-->
    <div class="design-box-double"></div> <!--width 50%-->
    <div class="design-box-single"></div> <!--width 100%-->
    <div class="design-box-single"></div> <!--width 100%-->
</div>
```

What I want is to use jQuery to check if the div has class with certain conditions then wrap with div row so that it is 100% width and the float:left divs stay visually nice and don't break the flow of the float.

Example end result:

```
<div class="collageWidgets">
  <div class="row"> <!--width 100%-->
     <div class="design-box-double"></div> <!--width 50%-->
  </div>
  <div class="row"> <!--width 100%-->
     <div class="design-box-triple"></div> <!--width 33%-->
     <div class="design-box-triple"></div> <!--width 33%-->
     <div class="design-box-triple"></div> <!--width 33%-->
  </div>
  <div class="row"> <!--width 100%-->
     <div class="design-box-double"></div> <!--width 50%-->
     <div class="design-box-double"></div> <!--width 50%-->
  </div>
  <div class="row"><!--width 100%-->
     <div class="design-box-single"></div> <!--width 100%-->
  </div>
  <div class="row"><!--width 100%-->
     <div class="design-box-single"></div> <!--width 100%-->
  </div>
  <div class="row"> <!--width 100%-->
     <div class="design-box-triple"></div> <!--width 33%-->
     <div class="design-box-triple"></div> <!--width 33%-->
     <!-- Example missing triple, but won't look messed up because it is wrapped with a row 100% width, display block, and clearfix-->
  </div>
</div><!--End of Collage Widget Div-->
```

Here is the jQuery that I have with double and single working. **I am struggling on the triple code.** The divs with design-box-triple.

Here is my logic thinking:

I need to check if the previous object parent has a class="row" && if div has class design-box-triple. If it does, then push that first widget that has design-box-triple into an array. Then check if the next object has design-box-triple class, if not then wrap the triple widget in div class = row. Then I need to check if the first class has design-box-triple, and the next has design-box-triple, then next next has design-box-triple wrap all in a div class = row. But if there are only two divs with class design-box-triple next to each other then wrap that in a row.

Here is the code that I have:

```
(function() {
var widgetArray = $(".careerCollageWidgets").find(".career-widget");
var prevClass = '';
var prevObject = '';
var prevPrevObject = '';
var tripleArray = [];
console.log(widgetArray.length);

$(widgetArray).each(function(index, value){
    console.log($(this));
    var widget = $(this);
    if (widget.hasClass('design-box-single')){
        widget.wrapAll('<div class="row"></div>');
        prevClass = 'design-box-single';
    } else if (widget.hasClass('design-box-double')){

        if(prevClass == 'design-box-double' && !prevObject.parent().hasClass('row')) {
            //var previousArray = [prevObject, widget];
            prevObject.add(widget).wrapAll('<div class="row"></div>');
        } else if (!widget.next().hasClass('design-box-double')){
            widget.wrapAll('<div class="row"></div>');
        }

        prevClass = 'design-box-double';

    } else if (widget.hasClass('design-box-triple')){
        tripleArray.push(widget);
        if (!prevObject.parent().hasClass('row')){
            tripleArray.push(widget);

            console.log(tripleArray);
            console.log("tripleArray");
            //tripleArray.wrap('<div class="row"></div>');
        }
        //else if(prevClass == 'design-box-triple' && !prevObject.parent().hasClass('row')) {

        //  if (!widget.next().hasClass('design-box-triple')){
        //      prevObject.add(widget).wrapAll('<div class="row"></div>');
        //  }

        //} 
        //else if (!widget.next().hasClass('design-box-triple')){
        //  widget.wrapAll('<div class="row"></div>');
        //}
        prevClass = 'design-box-triple';
    }

    prevObject = widget;
});
```

})();

```
$('.row').css({'width':'100%', 'display':'block'});
$('.row').addClass('clearfix');
```

Comment: The CSS you're applying to `.row` is the default for a div. Shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7jpy4/

```
$('.single').wrap('<div class="row"></div>');

var doubles = $('.double');
for (var i=0; i<doubles.length;) {
   i += doubles.eq(i).nextUntil(':not(.double)').andSelf()
       .wrapAll('<div class="row"></div>').length;
}

var triples = $('.triple');
for (var i=0; i<triples.length;) {
   i += triples.eq(i).nextUntil(':not(.triple)').andSelf()
       .wrapAll('<div class="row"></div>').length;
}
```

Notice that I broke up your class names to simplify things for this demo. Also, you'd have to put a counter in to prevent stacks of doubles and triples if you ever have more than two or three consecutive, respectively.

Inspiration from [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328208/jquery-how-to-wrap-div-around-multiple-of-the-same-class-elements).

Comment: I added .slice(0,3) to select three consecutive of the same type.